# Increment version number causing application to run older version

Tags: visual-studio, versioning, windows

I ran into an issue today where my preview server was running an older version of a project instead of the most recently published version. The most recently published version was 1.0.4.10, but after some testing, I determined that version was not the version of the application that the server was retrieving.

After trying a few things, I tried publishing a new version under 1.0.5.0 instead of continuing with the 1.0.4.xx numbering, and that fixed the issue.

VS's auto increment feature recommended 1.0.4.10, but is there an issue with this being the same as 1.0.4.1? So maybe it was running 1.0.4.9? Or something behind the scenes I'm not aware of?